# Locating a sequence in a sorted array

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

I read the following question: [Searching an element in a sorted array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4223/80949) and I thought that I could give it a try in Python.

Given a sorted list of integers and an integer. Return the (index) bounds of the sequence of this element in the list.

Example:

```python
l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]

0 not found in list
1:(0, 0)
2:(1, 2)
3:(3, 5)
4:(6, 11)
5 not found in list
6:(12, 12)
7:(13, 13)
8:(14, 14)
9:(15, 18)
```

Here is my program (using Python 3).
It uses a dichotomic search and returns the bounds to help the search of the start and end of the sequence.

```python
def main():
    l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]
    print(l)
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            print(find_sequence(i, l))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))


def find_sequence(x, l):
    """Return a tuple (begin, end) containing the index bounds of the sequence of x"""
    left, found, right = dichotomic_search(x, l)
    begin = outside_bound(x, l, left, found)
    end = outside_bound(x, l, right, found)
    return begin, end

def outside_bound(x, l, outside, inside):
    """Return the outside bound of the sequence"""
    if l[outside] == x:
        return outside

    middle = -1
    previous_middle = -2
    while middle != previous_middle:
        previous_middle = middle
        middle = (outside + inside) // 2
        if l[middle] == x:
            inside = middle
        else:
            outside = middle
    return inside


def dichotomic_search(x, l):
    """Return a tuple of indexes (left, found, right)

    left: leftmost index where x might be found
    found: index where x is
    right: rightmost index where x might be found
    """
    left = 0
    right = len(l) - 1

    if l[left] > x or l[right] < x:
        raise Exception(str(x) + ' not found in list')

    if l[left] == x:
        return left, left, right
    if l[right] == x:
        return left+1, right, right # we know that l[left]!=x

    while left < right:
        middle = (left + right) // 2
        if l[middle] == x:
            return left, middle, right
        elif l[middle] < x:
            left = middle + 1 # to prevent fixed point
        elif l[middle] > x:
            right = middle # impossible to do -1 because of the integer division

    raise Exception(str(x) + ' not found in list')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not so fond of the `middle != previous_middle`, but I didn't find a more elegant way (yet).

Comment: Do you know about `bisect` (i.e. did you implement that search yourself on purpose)?

Comment: I implemented it on purpose (and I think using bisect the search for the second extremity of the sequence can't be optimized - whereas I'm reusing the bounds of my dichotomic search)

Comment: Why not just `bisect_left(l, x), bisect_right(l, x) - 1`? The worry about reusing the bounds seems misplaced to me. In the average case you're searching an array that's half the size—but it's a binary search, so it only saves you one iteration. Whereas the `bisect` module has a fast C implementation.

Comment: "it only saves you one iteration" only if you search the element. If you search the bounds, it might turn out to be worse. For instance, search for `1`: `{0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}`.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you're approach is too complicated. Just create a function that finds the first occurrence of an element using a binary search, an another function that finds the last one. And then you can write:

```
def find_indexes(xs, x)
  start = find_first_index(xs, x)
  return ((start, find_last_index(xs, x, start=start)) if start else None)
```

For a simple implementation of `find_first_index` and `find_last_index`, check [bisect.bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) and [bisect.bisect_right](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py).

Comment: My approach might be complicated, but it aims at being efficient. When you call `find_last_index`, The first part of the work might have already been done by the `find_first_index` (the part "finding the index"). What I could do though, is "improve" `bisect.bisect_left` to remember the first time the element was found (to use it as a bound for `find_last_index`)

Comment: In `find_last_index`, one could use `first_index` as a lower bound for instance!

Comment: Yeah, I know, but in a O(log n) algorithm like a binary-search it does not matter much. Anyway, updated, the bisect functions have such argument.

Comment: (you could use the same name as bisect: `lo`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have performance notes, but you shouldn't be raising bare exceptions. There's more specific ones you can raise, so you should raise whatever's relevant to the problem. In this case? It's a `ValueError`, as the user has supplied values that are invalid.

```
raise ValueError(str(x) + ' not found in list')
```

This has the added bonus that you don't need to catch other, unrelated errors with your `try except` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @tokland suggestion, here is what I came with:
The `find_left_bound` returns some bounds that can be used by `find_right_bound` to reduce the search area.

```
def main():
    l = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,9,9,9]
    print(l)
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            print(str(i) + ': ' + str(find_sequence(l, i)))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))


def find_sequence(l, x):
    """Return a tuple (begin, end) containing the index bounds of the sequence of x"""
    begin, (left, right) = find_left_bound(l, x)
    if l[begin] != x:
        raise Exception(str(x) + ' not found in list')
    end = find_right_bound(l, x, left, right)
    return begin, end


def find_left_bound(l, x):
    left = 0
    right = len(l)
    lbound = left # bounds for the 'right_bound' search
    rbound = right
    while left < right:
        middle = (left + right) // 2
        if l[middle] < x:
            left = middle + 1
        else:
            right = middle

            # If it's relevant, improve the bounds for the right search
            if l[middle] > x:
                rbound = middle
            elif middle > lbound:
                lbound = middle
    return left, (lbound, rbound)

def find_right_bound(l, x, left, right):
    while left < right:
        middle = (left + right) // 2
        if l[middle] > x:
            right = middle
        else:
            left = middle + 1
    return left - 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I should rename `find_left_bound` (since it does actually a bit more), but I'm unable to find a suitable name...

I don't see other ways to improve the efficiency.